# finding maximum of a subarray

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Preprocess an array A in O(n log n) time so that you can answer queries of the form
findmax(i,j): find the maximum value in an interval [i; j] (that is, the maximum value
among the array elements A[i],A[i + 1],...,A[j]) in O(1)) time per query.

Additional question: Show how to preprocess in O(n) time so that you can answer the above queries in O(log n) time.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Right now it looks like you've copied and pasted this question verbatim from a problem set or coding challenge website, which gives us very little reason to want to help you at all.

Comment: I have tried DP and this is past year informatics olympiad question. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is known as range minimum (maximum) query - [RMQ](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=lowestCommonAncestor). The link basically answers both of your questions.

The classic solutions are dynamic programming and segment trees.